# XML structure to another XML structure using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to XSLT and have been stuck on a problem for to long.
This XML document's structure is throwing me and I don't know how to go about restructuring it.

The sample XML is below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<data>
 <source>192.***.**.**</source>
<device>
 <Id>1234</Id>
</device>
<update>
 <time>20141014T060927.557+0000</time>
 <field>
  <id>1</id>
  <dtype>float</dtype>
  <value>-31.917587</value>
 </field>
 <field>
  <id>2</id>
  <dtype>float</dtype>
  <value>115.806841</value>
 </field>
 <field>
  <id>3</id>
  <dtype>int</dtype>
  <value>3</value>
 </field>
 <field>
  <id>4</id>
  <dtype>int</dtype>
  <value>1</value>
 </field>
</update>
</data>
```

In this structure the *id* element is in fact the field's name while the *dtype* is the field's datatype. The *value* is the value.

The desired structure is this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<data>
    <source>192.168.20.21</source>
    <device>
        <Id>1234</Id>
    </device>
    <update>
        <field>
            <column1>-31.917587</column1>
            <column2>115.806841</column2>
            <column3>3</column3>
            <column4>1</column4>
            <time>20141014T060927.557+0000</time>
        </field>
    </update>
</data>
```

I understand that XSLT is the only way to go about it but have not worked out how best to construct a style sheet that will get me from the existing structure to the desired one.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your XSLT version?

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to name element name with a running number: column1 ... columnN

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck with this (rather trivial) task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="update">
    <xsl:for-each select="field">
        <xsl:element name="column{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>        
    <xsl:apply-templates select="time"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwe3ce

Comment: Thank you for the help.